# Does GCP Cloud Armor support TCP load balancer? I am unable to add TCP load balancers as a Targets in Cloud Armor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, network-security

In the GCP cloud armor documentation, it is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/managed-protection-overview?authuser=4&_ga=2.35955816.-958500654.1600324886&_gac=1.91214568.1604408592.Cj0KCQjw59n8BRD2ARIsAAmgPmLevDI2fhN0THMDP1nI4Y3Mz-yc2zE-1MgS0iKyVNuJO6xabx18WoUaAiIpEALw_wcB#standard_tier_versus_plus_tier), that it supports HTTP(S) and TCP load balancers to be configured. But I am unable to add TCP load balancer as a Target in Cloud Armor as it doesn't show the TCP load balancer in the target list.

Answer (score 2):

I am editing this response since `Cloud Armor` covers more Load Balancers as per today's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview) the following are covered:

- Global external Application Load Balancer (HTTP/HTTPS)
- Classic Application Load Balancer (HTTP/HTTPS)
- Regional external Application Load Balancer (HTTP/HTTPS)
- Classic proxy Network Load Balancer (TCP/SSL)
- External passthrough Network Load Balancer (TCP/UDP)
- Protocol forwarding
- VMs with public IP addresses

`Cloud Armor` capabilities may be different for App & TCP LBs given their inspection at OSI level.

Comment: it's good to add that currently cloud armor does NOT work with L7 or internal GCP load balancer as can be seen here: